# How do I flip a sprite only on the x-axis with kaboom.js?

Tags: javascript, kaboom

I want to flip my character to move left so that I dont have to animate a new left animation on every character (Yeah Im lazy). Is there an easy way to do this?

-Using kaboom.js

```
onKeyDown("a", () => { 
  player.move(-SPEED, 0), //moves sprite
  onKeyPress("a", () => { 
    player.play("RunSide"), //plays animation
    player.scale = -1, //trying to flip it here :)
    onKeyRelease("a", () => { 
      player.stop(), //stops animation
      player.frame = 0 
    }) 
  }) 
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

player.flipX(true) should work assuming that player is the sprite that you created

Answer (score 0):

The demos on the Kaboom website has an example
https://kaboomjs.com/play?demo=sprite

```
onKeyDown("left", () => {
    player.move(-SPEED, 0)
    player.flipX(true)
    if (player.isGrounded() && player.curAnim() !== "run") {
        player.play("run")
    }
})

onKeyDown("right", () => {
    player.move(SPEED, 0)
    player.flipX(false)
    if (player.isGrounded() && player.curAnim() !== "run") {
        player.play("run")
    }
})
```

I think the `.flipX()` method is toggled on/off, so here it needs toggled off when the opposite direction is pressed.

By the way Kaboom has a Discord for help